# Updating a document in sharded document store- ravendb

Tags: ravendb, sharding

Here updating a document in ravendb sharded document store seems to be hectic since i am using  sess.store with the id to update any given document, I am using store to avoid concurrent updates I am using the following code to update.

This is the document structure

```
public class DistributorRechargePayment:IPOCOLogInfo
            {

               [JsonIgnore]
               public Guid? Etag;
               public String Id { get; set; }
               public String ReceiptNo { get; set; }
               public TransactionTypes TransactionType { get; set; }
               public String PaymentId { get; set; }
        }
```

here is the code for update

```
sess.Store(distbpayment, myguid1, distbpayment.Id);
```

and in my shard strategy i have referred to a shard key with the some other value as follows

```
 var shards = new Dictionary<string, IDocumentStore>
            {
                {"zero", new DocumentStore {Url = "http://localhost:8080"}},
                {"one", new DocumentStore {Url = "http://localhost:8081"}},
                {"two", new DocumentStore {Url = "http://localhost:8082"}},

            };
        shardStrategy = new ShardStrategy(shards).ShardingOn<DistributorRechargePayment>(x => x.ReceiptNo);
```

Now wat happens here is when i store for the first time the document is moved to the correct shard for example if receiptno is one-123455 this document goes to the correct shard. And when i update through the store again when i already have the document id as one-DistributorRechargePayment-1 so id is re-written as one-one-DistributorRechargePayment-1 which throws an error.

Here i could have used sess.saveshanges(). But to ensure optimistic concurrency i need sess.store(). I need a solution to use optimistic concurrency and also achieve sharded store

Comment: How do you save the document?

Comment: using sess.savechanges() after the store method.